# Image below Navbar

Tags: html, css

It's been awhile since I've worked on a website. I'm trying to create a website for my company. I have a navigation bar, but I want to have an image below the nav bar.

I tried looking at other posts  but couldn't figure out to do this.

what i want to do is like this image. I do what to make it repeatable
like a tile, so it extends to the end. Thanks

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BMZY.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<title>Modern Studio </title>


<link href="css/style3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container-fluid"> 


          <div class="navbar-header">
            <ul">
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div> 
     </div>  



    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-image: url("img/tileBG.gif");
    width:100%;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background-image: url("img/tileBG.gif");
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    position:fixed;
}



.logo{
    float:left;
    margin-left: -250px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.nav{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: That would be great if you could upload your `tileBG.gif` to somewhere and add a working example via code snippet or JsFiddle

Comment: This may be a repeat post, but Thanks for taking the time to help with this, I did get it to work. Sorry for the confusion with my original post, my first time posting. For some reason tileBG.gif, wasn't loading. I was working offline. but as soon as up loaded to my web server it loaded correctly. next time i'll try uploading to JsFiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

not sure of the question, But to repeat the tiles side way, you can use the [repeat-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-repeat)

```
.header {
    background-image:url("img/tileBG.gif");
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `background-repeat` style for patterned background graphic while

- value `repeat-x` represent the background will repeat itself horizontally but not vertically
- value `repeat-y` represent repeat itself vertically but not horizontally and
- value `repeat` means repeat itself both horizontally and vertically.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Zay_DEV/z4k97ytm/

```css
body{
    background-image: url("img/tileBG.gif");
    width:100%;
}

.container{
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header{
    background-image: url("img/tileBG.gif");
    width:100%;
    top: 0;
    position:fixed;
}



.logo{
    float:left;
    margin-left: -250px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: black;
}

li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
}

.nav{
    float:left;
}

/* New Code */
.header {
    background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/88/47/70/500_F_88477046_P7TlUumCGSrEsFEKZs0xNWoJif4drHP6.jpg");
    background-size: 10%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
.header a { background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); color: #fff; }
```

```html
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container-fluid"> 


          <div class="navbar-header">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Custom</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sign in</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Checkout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div> 
     </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Sorry for the confusion with my post. My main problem was my original link wasn't loading and I thought maybe I did something wrong in my css file or html. But I uploaded the file to my web server and the background loaded.